# Powershell and XML protocol

Tags: xml, powershell, protocols

I'm trying to communicate with our telephone exchange with powershell via XML Slican Protocol

Interface:

```
Medium: Ethernet
Protocol: TCP/IP
Port: 5529
```

XML frame structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XCTIP>
  <Module>
    <Command>
      <Data>...</Data>
    </Command>
  </Module> 
</XCTIP>
```

Answer is also in XML.

I already build a working XML frame structure, which I tested with dedicated Slican tool.

Sending a packet requires also IP, login and pass.

Should I use Invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod? Which method? How the request should look like?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts for this.

I had to implement similar functionality and I've used successfully `DownloadData`. By the way first of all that needs to be done is to allow script execution in **PowerShell**. Running **PowerShell** as an *admin* execute the
following:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

OR

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Then I've written the following code that managed to download data with simple retry policy.

```
function executeDownloadWithRetry {
    Param(
     [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$pathNew
     )       

     for($i=1; $i -le $numberOfAttempts; $i++) {
        try {
            DownloadData -target "Comprehensive-Fixed" -folder "$pathNew" -userName $userNameForService -password $passwordForService -shoudRethrowErrors $TRUE
            break
        } catch {
            # Should check to retry: error record is in $_
            # simplified formula for back-off
            $seconds = [math]::pow(2, $i) - 1
            LogWrite "Attempt #$($i) failed"
            LogWrite "Retrying in $seconds second(s)"
            Start-Sleep -Second $seconds 
        }            
     }   
}
```

To execute it:

```
executeDownloadWithRetry -pathNew $pathNew
```

Here `$pathNew` stands for the folder where the data should be saved.

#### UPD #1

Forgot to include the main function `DownloadData` :)

```
function DownloadData {
    Param(
     [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$target,
     [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$userName,
     [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$password,
     [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$folder,
     [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$shoudRethrowErrors
     )

    $authUrl = "https://URL/Account/LogOn"
    $fileListUrl = "https://URL/Files/RawFormat?"
    $fileUrl = "https://URL/Files/GetFile?"
    $localDir = $folder

    $postData = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("UserName=" +
    [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($userName) +
    "&Password=" + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($password))

    $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($authUrl)
    $webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    $webRequest.ContentLength = $postData.Length
    $webRequest.Method = "POST"
    ([System.Net.HttpWebRequest] $webRequest).CookieContainer = new-object System.Net.CookieContainer

    $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
    $requestStream.Write($postData, 0, $postData.Length)
    $requestStream.Flush()
    $requestStream.Close()

    $webResponse = [System.Net.HttpWebResponse] $webRequest.GetResponse()
    $cookies = ([System.Net.HttpWebRequest] $webRequest).CookieContainer.GetCookies($webRequest.RequestUri)
    $theCookie = $cookies["fileretrieval.aspxauth"]
    $theCookie2 = $cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"]
    $cookieHeader = ([System.Net.HttpWebRequest]     $webRequest).CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader($webRequest.RequestUri)

    if ($webResponse.StatusCode -ne [System.Net.HttpStatusCode]::OK -or $theCookie -eq $null -or $theCookie2 -eq $null)
    {

        LogWrite "Authentication request failed."   
        return
    }

    LogWrite "Authenticated successfully."

    if ($target -eq "") { $target = "All" }

    $webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
    $webClient.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, $cookieHeader)
    $fileList = $webClient.DownloadString($fileListUrl + "target=" + $target)


    try
    {
        foreach($f in $fileList -split "`r`n")
        {
            $c = $f.split('|')      
            if ($c.length -gt 1)
            {           
                $src = $fileUrl + "type=" + $c[0] + "&dirName=" + $c[1] + "&fileName=" + $c[2]
                $dest = $localDir + $c[2]
                LogWrite ("downloading " + $c[0] + " : " + $c[2]);
                $webClient.DownloadFile($src, $dest)
            }
        }
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
        LogWrite "Error copying file, details below."
        LogWrite $error[0] | format-list * -f
        if($shoudRethrowErrors -eq $TRUE) {
            throw $error[0]
        }
        return
    }
    LogWrite "Finished."
}
```